# Get size of a secondary monitor

Tags: java, swing, screen, multiple-monitors

I seem to struggle to get the size of more than one monitor in Java;

So I made a little window that is supposed to display a screen's dimensions, it works fine for my primary monitor, now I would like to be able to determine the size of the monitor it's on, I used `getLocation()` to know where my JFrame is, but I don't know how to get the size of that monitor, i can only get the primary one, or even their total size.

Comment: Please get into the habit of searching Stack Overflow for existing answers before posting questions. There's a very good chance that what you're asking has been asked before.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get down into the [`GraphicsEnvironment`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html) which will give you access to all [`GraphicsDevice`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html) available on the system.

Essentially from there, you need loop through each `GraphicsDevice` and test to see if the window is within the bounds of the a given `GraphicsDevice`

The fun part, is what to do if the window spans across multiple screens...

```
public static GraphicsDevice getGraphicsDevice(Component comp) {

    GraphicsDevice device = null;
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice lstGDs[] = ge.getScreenDevices();
    ArrayList<GraphicsDevice> lstDevices = new ArrayList<GraphicsDevice>(lstGDs.length);

    if (comp != null && comp.isVisible()) {
        Rectangle parentBounds = comp.getBounds();
        /*
         * If the component is not a window, we need to find its location on the
         * screen...
         */
        if (!(comp instanceof Window)) {
            Point p = new Point(0, 0);
            SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen(p, comp);
            parentBounds.setLocation(p);
        }

        // Get all the devices which the window intersects (ie the window might expand across multiple screens)
        for (GraphicsDevice gd : lstGDs) {
            GraphicsConfiguration gc = gd.getDefaultConfiguration();
            Rectangle screenBounds = gc.getBounds();
            if (screenBounds.intersects(parentBounds)) {
                lstDevices.add(gd);
            }
        }

        // If there is only one device listed, return it...
        // Otherwise, if there is more then one device, find the device
        // which the window is "mostly" on
        if (lstDevices.size() == 1) {
            device = lstDevices.get(0);
        } else if (lstDevices.size() > 1) {
            GraphicsDevice gdMost = null;
            float maxArea = 0;
            for (GraphicsDevice gd : lstDevices) {
                int width = 0;
                int height = 0;
                GraphicsConfiguration gc = gd.getDefaultConfiguration();
                Rectangle bounds = gc.getBounds();
                Rectangle2D intBounds = bounds.createIntersection(parentBounds);
                float perArea = (float) ((intBounds.getWidth() * intBounds.getHeight()) / (parentBounds.width * parentBounds.height));
                if (perArea > maxArea) {
                    maxArea = perArea;
                    gdMost = gd;
                }
            }

            if (gdMost != null) {
                device = gdMost;
            }
        }
    }

    return device;
}
```